# How to get the nice and desirable paths for curved arrows inside a table or control their end points?

Tags: tables, tikz-arrows, arrow-curve

I want to plot the following in `LaTeX` (off course in a way that looks more beautiful):

[image]

So far I have reached the following.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{% <---- BEWARE
            \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=2pt] (char) {#1};}}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{cccccccc}
\cline{4-5}
 & & & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\circled{M1}}\tikzmark{b} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{M2} & & & \\
\cline{4-5}
 & & & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{R1} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{R2} & & & \\
\cline{4-5}
 & & &  &  & & & \\
\cline{1-2}\cline{4-5}\cline{7-8}
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\circled{M1}}\tikzmark{a}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{M2} & & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\circled{M1}}\tikzmark{x} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{M2} & & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\circled{M1}}\tikzmark{c} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{M2} \\
\cline{1-2}\cline{4-5}\cline{7-8}
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{R1}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{R2} & & R1 & R2 & & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{R1} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{R2} \\
\cline{1-2}\cline{4-5}\cline{7-8}
 & & &  &  & & & \\
\cline{4-5}
 & & & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\circled{M1}}\tikzmark{d} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{M2} & & & \\
\cline{4-5}
 & & & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{R1} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{R2} & & & \\
\cline{4-5}
  \end{tabular}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture, yshift=.25\baselineskip, shorten >=.5pt, shorten <=.5pt]
    \draw [->] ({pic cs:a}) [bend right] to ({pic cs:x});
    \draw [->] ({pic cs:b}) [bend right] to ({pic cs:x});
    \draw [->] ({pic cs:c}) [bend right] to ({pic cs:x});
    \draw [->] ({pic cs:d}) [bend right] to ({pic cs:x});
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I cannot control the arrows and it seems they tend to end in one particular point. How can I choose where the end point can be? Or maybe something in LaTeX that automatically sets some path for the arrows so that they would intersect the least places in the figure?

Comment: the circled environment already defines each circle as a node with name and then you are providing another name with the help of tikzmark - could that be the problem

Comment: You mean all the circles are named M1? But that makes everything confusing

Comment: Loath as I am to say it, but you don't actually need tikzmark here.  As js bibra says, you already have nodes in your code and they define coordinates.  You just need to make their names unique (they currently are all called `char`).  However, I think it would be easier to redraw the whole diagram as a single tikzpicture, probably making good use of the matrix nodes.

Comment: I am sorry but I dont understand how your suggestion hrlps me. I need all of the nodes to be named M1 and cannot rename them

Comment: When we talk about the **name** of a node we aren't referring to its _contents_. The name of a node is something that tikz can use to refer to it. It's often specified via `\node[options] (name) {contents};`.  If you extend the `\circled` macro to take a second argument and use that for the name then you could use those directly without tikzmark.

Comment: I get what you are saying now. But still cannot implement it. Searched a lot but nothing

Comment: Also I dont think naming the circled ones instead of using tikz solves the problem here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a version without tikzmark which works by assigning different names to the nodes that you are already creating in the `\circled` command.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/563076/86}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand*\circled[2][char]{\tikz[baseline=(#1.base),remember picture]{% <---- BEWARE
            \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=2pt] (#1) {#2};}}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{cccccccc}
\cline{4-5}
 & & & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\circled[b]{M1}} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{M2} & & & \\
\cline{4-5}
 & & & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{R1} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{R2} & & & \\
\cline{4-5}
 & & &  &  & & & \\
\cline{1-2}\cline{4-5}\cline{7-8}
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\circled[a]{M1}}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{M2} & & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\circled[x]{M1}}& \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{M2} & & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\circled[c]{M1}} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{M2} \\
\cline{1-2}\cline{4-5}\cline{7-8}
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{R1}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{R2} & & R1 & R2 & & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{R1} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{R2} \\
\cline{1-2}\cline{4-5}\cline{7-8}
 & & &  &  & & & \\
\cline{4-5}
 & & & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\circled[d]{M1}} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{M2} & & & \\
\cline{4-5}
 & & & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{R1} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{R2} & & & \\
\cline{4-5}
  \end{tabular}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture, yshift=.25\baselineskip, shorten >=.5pt, shorten <=.5pt]
    \draw [->] (a) [bend right] to (x);
    \draw [->] (b) [bend right] to (x);
    \draw [->] (c) [bend right] to (x);
    \draw [->] (d) [bend right] to (x);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: grids with arrows between them]

Comment: the R1 and R2 in center require the same treatment of multicolumn

Comment: @jsbibra I took the code from the question and made the changes needed to get the arrows to work.  The R1 and R2 are like that in the original code so I left them that way.  If I were going to look at modifying the original code, I would do the whole thing as a single tikzpicture.